# Reverse geocoding Google API without map javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, geolocation

I'm working on a function that takes from the javascript geolocation functionality the latitude and longitude of a certain place, puts those values inside a https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode url and given a country and a specific time, redirects to a site or to another.

My question is, and i´ve really done tons of research. Can I do that?

This is why i´m asking.

In the ToS  https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_4 says: 
" No use of Content without a Google map. Unless the Maps APIs Documentation expressly permits you to do so, you will not use the Content in a Maps API Implementation without a corresponding Google map. For example, you may display Street View imagery without a corresponding Google map because the Maps APIs Documentation expressly permits this use. "

Also, am I to inform the user that i´m using such service? Because that it´s also amongst their ToS.

Thank u so much, I´m quite lost regarding that, because I don´t know if the page might get shut down if i use my function and dont put a map on the page nor if i dont alert of the use to the users.

Comment: I can't give a definitive answer, but after reading the documentation, it doesn't seem so.

Comment: Standard plan seems to be bound to display maps. Maybe there is any option for [Premium plan](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/overview) users. Try [contact Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/), hopefully they can address your question better.